# Error converting data type varchar to numeric when converting substring to decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, decimal, varchar

I have a table that includes a VARCHAR column populated with values like

*Employee is not entitled to SSP because their average weekly earnings are below LEL.Average Earnings: £44.13750*

[image]

I am trying to extract the value after the **£** sign so I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    ClientId
    , Max(PayPeriod) As PeriodNo
, CASE WHEN MAX(Comment) like '%£%' THEN 
    CAST(MAX(right(Comment, charindex('£', reverse(Comment))-1) )AS DECIMAL(5,2)) 
    ELSE 0 END AS AvgEarnings2      
FROM 
    t_PayrollSSPEmployeeComment 
WHERE 
    comment like '%LEL%' AND comment like '%£%'
        GROUP BY 
            ClientID
```

I only want to retrieve the value so I can cast it to decimal like `110.25`

But I am getting an error

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

I can get the value with or without the £ sign, but I need to cast it to the right number of decimal places for a report.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like you have some illegal characters in the string-value. Perhaps your decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) function can be used to extract number after character `£`.

```
    SELECT 
    ClientId
    ,Max(PayPeriod) As PeriodNo
    ,CASE WHEN MAX(Comment) like '%£%' THEN      
     CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(Comment),2,LEN(MAX(Comment))) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        ELSE 0 END AS AvgEarnings2      
    FROM t_PayrollSSPEmployeeComment 
    WHERE comment like '%LEL%' AND comment like '%£%'
     GROUP BY ClientID
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have an error `Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.`

Comment: @OurManinBananas Can you try with `DECIMAL(18,2)` updated answer, I hope your Comment column doesn't have any other character than `£`.

Comment: I tried that, same error, so will have to check the string more carefully, stripping out everything like line feed and so on

Comment: @OurManinBananas Without any sample data it's difficult to provide any good solution.

Comment: I have added some sample data

Comment: it looks like there is an extra linefeed or carriage-return char at the end of the string...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher, use Try_Convert function:

```
Try_Convert (Decimal(5, 2), MAX(right(Comment, charindex('£', reverse(Comment))-1) ))
```

and see, wherever your error code does not convert the expression to decimal type, instead of error, the result will be `null` and check the problem with that value.